# Jquery datatables callback on search

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Jquery datatables plugin to generate my tables. In every row I have a button to open the child data. The button has the class "fa-plus". To trigger this I use a simple Jquery on click function.

```
fnDrawCallback: function() {
      $('.fa-plus').click(function() {
           // some functionality
      });
},
```

This work great only even if you go to the next page it works as the function is reloaled with the fnDrawCallback callback. Only when you use the search option in the dattatables the callback is not triggered. Also not with the fnInfoCallback function.

Does anyone know if there is an callback on the search function of Jequery datatables?

I'm looking for a callback that is triggered on any change of datatables.

Comment: How are you implementing the search? On my project with dataTables, fnDrawCallback fires every time the table is redrawn after a search is applied. Are you calling draw() on the table?

Answer (score 5):

You can look at Datatable [events](https://datatables.net/reference/event/)

e.g.

```
$('#table').on('search.dt', function (e, settings) {
    // ...
});
```

Does that help?

Comment: I just found out a have a other problem, the original function fnDrawCallback works fine as it gives the trigger. But with a search of a sort the row index is changed. Any idee of to get the correct row index?

Comment: Get the index when?  How?  Can you post a code sample?